# RX: Perform disposal when RefCount of a Subject reaches 0

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a simple class as follow:

```
internal class DataProvider : IDataProvider
{
    private readonly Subject<string> _dataChangeSubject = new System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject<string>();
    private IObservable<string> _dataChangeObservable;

    public IObservable ObserveDataChange()
    {
        return _dataChangeObservable ?? (_dataChangeObservable = _dataChangeSubject.Publish().RefCount());
    }
}
```

The above is just an extract of the actual class, which has other code to call `Subject.OnNext()` to notify the changes.

What I want to know is if there's a way to know when `RefCount` of the published subject reaches 0, so that I can dispose the subject and perform some other clean up operations.

Comment: What `_dataChangeSubject.Publish().RefCount()` returns? From the method name, it should return integer, but from your usage it seems returns `IObservable<string>`.

Comment: Yes, `IConnectableObservable<T>.RefCount()` returns `IObservable<string>`.

Comment: Can you introduce an event `RefCountChanged` and subscribe to it?

Comment: Where should I introduce this event? `RefCount()` is provided by reactive extensions, and I don't know when the internal subscription ref count changes and this is exactly what I need to find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With RefCount(), the sequence completes when subscriptions reach 0. So you can just use [Finally](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html) to listen sequence completion. For example:

```
internal class DataProvider
{
    private readonly Subject<string> _dataChangeSubject = new System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject<string>();
    private IObservable<string> _dataChangeObservable;

    public IObservable<string> ObserveDataChange()
    {
        return _dataChangeObservable ?? 
            (_dataChangeObservable = _dataChangeSubject.Finally(() => { /* Do cleanup here */ }).Publish().RefCount());
    }
}
```